# C: Why would using register be considered bad practice?

Tags: c, cpu-registers

I read one some question on SO (unfortunately I don't remember the question) that two keywords that should never be used are `goto` and `register`.
Now, I didn't even know what on earth `register` is before this, so I looked it up and found another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068721/when-to-use-registers-in-c) that showed some uses for registers. Sure, register values have their disadvantages, but I also see some uses. Plus, the compiler can always veto the choice to actually use the registers. So if you know the limitations when using `register`, why not use them?

Comment: First of all, C and C++ are two very different languages, with their own distinct specifications. And the keyword `register` is specified differently in the two languages.

Comment: This seems identical to the question you linked really

Comment: As for `goto`, please do some research about *spaghetti code*.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I removed the C++ tag. @M.M the reason why I asked the question is that I basically never see the keyword being used anywhere and was wondering if it was considered bad practice by everyone.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware of why `goto` is very bad, I just said it because I was explaining the context in which I heard `register`.

Comment: *Misuse* of `goto` is bad, but there are niche uses for it that make code clearer and therefore better.  On the other hand, modern compilers do a better job of allocating registers than humans can, so declaring variables with `register` storage class gains you nothing, but it costs you the ability to take the variable's address with the `&` operator, and, therefore, the ability to access that variable indirectly.  `register` is functionally obsolete.  Not so much `goto`.

Comment: I remember having lately seen questions which were of the sort: "why is this code using `register` slower than without" - and the answer is "because you told the compiler to put **that** variable into a register"

Comment: I see. I guess now compilers are so optimized that they are far better at deciding whether to put a variable as a register or not.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 "compilers are optimised" is not the point. Compiler are far better than humans to generate efficient machine code, that's it. The fact that a compiler is optimised or not is another thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using compilers from circa pre-1990 with exuberant use of `register` could, and probably would, hobble them to placing too much faith in the programmer and generate non-optimal code.
2. Most (virtually all) compilers are now "smart" enough to determine themselves whether the given set of `register` variables are helpful and probably totally ignore them.
3. Circa 1973 (Unix V6), the `register` storage class was extremely valuable to scrunch PDP-11 code to compile small enough to so that the kernel could fit in its 64 KiB space.  Speed is fine, but in those days it was about code size.

Comment: I guess that does seem to make sense. Thank you for taking your time out to answer.

Comment: > the kernel could fit in its 64 KiB space   The mind boggles. I remember getting my feelings hurt 20 years ago when I got my hands on a Mandrake CD, and finding out it required a minimum of 64 MEGAbytes when I only had 16 megs on the 486.

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski:  Yep.  I do kind-of miss the good old days when it was *possible* to know everything about what was in the address space:  data and program.

Answer (score 3):

`register` is mostly a superfluous keyword that was historically used for manually optimizing code. Very old compilers were sometimes too dumb to realize that a variable that doesn't have its address taken could often be stored in a CPU register rather than on the stack, which is a major performance improvement.

Not only are registers the fastest type of memory in a computer, much faster than RAM where the stack sits. But if allocating in a register, the compiler can also leave out the extra code for pushing/popping the variable on the stack.

Normal, modern C programs should however never use `register` since compilers are nowadays much more capable than programmers when it comes to determining where to allocate a certain variable. The keyword has been "de facto" obsolete since somewhere in the mid 1990s, though it has not been flagged formally obsolete by the C standard yet.

So if you encounter code containing `register`, it is either extremely old, or (far more likely) the programmer didn't quite have a clue what they were doing when they tried to manually optimize something.

---

There are some very limited, advanced "language-lawyer" uses of the keyword still. Namely that such a variable can never have its address taken. The address-of operator 6.5.3.2 states (emphasis mine):

> **The operand of the unary & operator** shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and **is not declared with the register storage-class specifier**.

This might matter in cases such as determining if accessing an uninitialized variable with indeterminate value is undefined behavior or merely unspecified behavior. See [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40674888/584518)